# How to access global Vue instance to programmatically added components in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Imagin a simple custom component like this:
MyComponent.vue

```html
<template>
  <p>
    <div>Test {{ message }}</div>
    <div ref="container"></div>
  </p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: ""
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$store);
  },
  methods: {
    show(message) {
      this.message = message;
      console.log(this.message);
      console.log(this.$refs.container);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I could use it like this in an other template:

```html
<template>
  <MyComponent />
</template>

<script>
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";
export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent,
  },
};
</script>
```

This is working fine. Now I would like to add this component programmatically.

```js
import { h, render } from "vue";

const vnode = h(MyComponent);
let el = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(el);
render(vnode, el);
vnode.type.methods.show(message);
```

This works, but I cannot access globally added instance like veux store, router, registered components and directives.
It looks like it renders on a own Vue instance. How add the global vue instance to this?
Also the message gets not updated via the show() method.
Also this.$refs.container is undefined.

Has anyone an idea to do this the right way?
I was able to do this using Vue2, but that is not working in Vue3

Comment: The code with vnode exists outside Vue instance. Consider explaining your case, it looks like XY problem. "vnode.type.methods.show" - it's a mistake to call it from `methods`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get as many apps as you want to use the same store. Have them import the same store instance from a location they can both access. Example:

```js
const { createApp, toRefs, defineComponent } = Vue;
const { createPinia, defineStore } = Pinia;

const pinia = createPinia();

const useStore = defineStore('my-store', {
  state: () => ({ counter: 0 })
})

const App1 = defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    return {
      add: () => store.counter++,
      sub: () => store.counter--
    }
  }
})

createApp(App1)
  .use(pinia)
  .mount('#app-1');

const App2 = defineComponent({
  template: `<h1>App 2</h1>
  <span v-text="counter"></span>`,
  setup: () => ({ ...toRefs(useStore())})
})

// let's delay creation of second app by a couple of seconds:
setTimeout(() => {
  createApp(App2)
    .use(pinia)
    .mount('#app-2')
}, 2e3);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia@2.0.11/dist/pinia.iife.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app-1">
  <h1>App 1</h1>
  <button @click="add">Add</button>
  <button @click="sub">Subtract</button>
</div>

<div id="app-2">
  <br>
  App2 not loaded yet..
</div>
```

Notes:

- `const { ...stuff } = Vue` becomes `import { ...stuff } from 'vue'`. Same for '`pinia`' imports.
- `const pinia = createPinia()` becomes `import { pinia } from './shared-location'`. At `'./shared-location'` you should have `export const pinia = createPinia()`

Both apps react to changes on the shared pinia instance. When either app adds a store to `pinia`, the other one gets access to the store and will be able to use it normally.
If using TypeScript you might need to use `declare` to type your stores.

Answer (score 1):

@tao Thanks for your idea.
I have made another solution. I have made dynamic component wrapper like this:

```html
<template>
  <component
    v-bind="currentProps"
    :is="currentComponentName"
    ref="currentComponent"
  />
</template>
<script>
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";

import { getCurrentInstance } from "vue";

export default {
  components: {
    MessageDialog,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      currentProps: {},
      currentComponentName: undefined,
    };
  },

  created() {
    let p = getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties;
    p.showMyComponent: this.showMyComponent,    
  },

  methods: {
    async showMyComponent(message, extraProps) {
      this.currentComponentName = "MyComponent";

      await this.$nextTick(() => {
        //wait untill next tick, else not access to  this.$refs.currentComponent
      });
      return this.$refs.currentComponent.show(message);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

From every where in my app I could call this.showMyComponent() and it will show it.